# Showing only one item in a list at a time

Tags: flutter

```
class secondcontrol extends GetxController{
  var _products = {}.obs;

  void addProduct(Product product) {
    if () {
      _products.removeWhere((key, value) => key == product);
    }
  }
```

i want to know what can i put between the brackets in the if command so that it allows me to show only one product for the list of products as chosen by the user

i tried all what i could think of trying to make it so that if more than one product is added then remove the previous one but nothing worked.

Answer (score 0):

To show only one product in the list at a time and remove the previous one when a new product is added, you can modify the `addProduct` method in your `secondcontrol` class. Here's how you can do it:

```
class SecondControl extends GetxController {
  var _products = {}.obs;
  Product? _currentProduct; // Variable to store the currently selected product

  void addProduct(Product product) {
    // Check if the product is not already in the list
    if (!_products.containsKey(product)) {
      // Remove the previous product if one exists
      if (_currentProduct != null) {
        _products.remove(_currentProduct);
      }

      // Set the current product to the new product
      _currentProduct = product;

      // Add the new product to the list
      _products[product] = true;
    }
  }
}
```

1. Add variable `_currentProduct` of type `Product?` (nullable) to keep track of the currently selected product.
2. In the `addProduct` method, check if the product is not already in the list using `_products.containsKey(product)`. If the product is already in the list, we don't add it again.
3. If the product is not in the list, proceed to remove the previous product (if one exists) by checking if `_currentProduct` is not null and then removing it from the `_products` map.
4. Set the `_currentProduct` to the new product that is being added.
5. Add the new product to the `_products` map with `_products[product] = true;`.

With this, only one product will be stored in the `_products` map at a time, and the previous product will be removed when a new one is added. This way, you can show only one product from the list as chosen by the user.